# Binding redux form input.value to a datetimepicker

Tags: react-native, react-redux, redux-form

I have a react native/redux/redux form setup which is (mostly) working, so everything is hooked up and running.

When I set up a form with an asynchronous update, I get a date field, for which I defined a custom component to be used as `<Field>` in redux-form.

Here's my component:

```javascript
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { Text, theme, Button, Block, Input } from "galio-framework";
import DateTimePicker from "react-native-modal-datetime-picker";

export class DateInputField extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { isDateTimePickerVisible: false };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }
  showDateTimePicker = () => {
    this.setState({ isDateTimePickerVisible: true });
  };
  hideDateTimePicker = () => {
    this.setState({ isDateTimePickerVisible: false });
  };
  handleChange = date => {
    console.log("date->" + date);
    this.setState({ isDateTimePickerVisible: false, date: date });
    this.props.input.onChange(date);
  };
  render() {
    const { input, meta, ...inputProps } = this.props;
    return (
      <Block style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.showDateTimePicker}>
          <DateTimePicker
            date={new Date(input.value)}
            cancelTextIOS="Annulla"
            confirmTextIOS="Conferma"
            isVisible={this.state.isDateTimePickerVisible}
            onConfirm={this.handleChange}
            onCancel={() => this.setState({ isDateTimePickerVisible: false })}
          />

          <Input
            color={"black"}
            editable={false}
            // onTouch={this.showDateTimePicker}
            // onFocus={this.showDateTimePicker}
            label={this.props.label}
            style={styles.input}
            placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
            value={
              this.state.date != undefined
                ? this.state.date.getDate() +
                  "/" +
                  (this.state.date.getMonth() + 1) +
                  "/" +
                  this.state.date.getFullYear()
                : "gg/mm/aaaa"
            }
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </Block>
    );
  }
}
export const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {},
  label: {},
  input: { flex: 1, color: "red", padding: 0, height: 50 }
});
```

and my field:

```javascript
<Field name={"consignment_date"} label="Fine" component={DateInputField} />
```

This component works, when I press the field the `datepicker` shows up with the correct date coming from the connected "model" field connected to it.

Now my problem is I can't figure way an elegant way to update the field value when the field is not updated by a human "onChange" event but the component's state is updated (and subsequently the component is rendered). I tried many combinations of setting the state `date` field, but I always ended in infinite loops because updating the state would cause a render, and so on.

I tried many Component lifecycle events to put my reading of the `input.value` and setting it on a state.displayedDate property, but I guess I am missing a very obvious way to do this because of my scarce knowledge of React's dynamics.

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting the solution that works:

```javascript
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { Text, theme, Button, Block, Input } from "galio-framework";
import DateTimePicker from "react-native-modal-datetime-picker";

export class DateInputField extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { isDateTimePickerVisible: false }; //no more date in state
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }
  showDateTimePicker = () => {
    this.setState({ isDateTimePickerVisible: true });
  };
  hideDateTimePicker = () => {
    this.setState({ isDateTimePickerVisible: false });
  };
  handleChange = date => {
    this.setState({ isDateTimePickerVisible: false });
    this.props.input.onChange(date);
  };
  render() {
    const { input, meta, ...inputProps } = this.props;
    return (
      <Block style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.showDateTimePicker}>
<DateTimePicker
            style={styles.label}
            date={new Date(input.value)}//date is transformed from input
            onDateChange={this.handleChange}
            cancelTextIOS="Annulla"
            confirmTextIOS="Conferma"
            isVisible={this.state.isDateTimePickerVisible}
            onConfirm={this.handleChange}
            onCancel={() => this.setState({ isDateTimePickerVisible: false })}
          />
          <Input
            color={"gray"}
            editable={false}
            enabled={false}
            label={this.props.label}
            style={styles.input}
            placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
            value={ //value is transformed to a date, then to the local string representation
              input.value !== ""
                ? new Date(input.value).toLocaleDateString()
                : new Date().toLocaleDateString()
            }
          />

        </TouchableOpacity>
      </Block>
    );
  }
}
export const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {},

  input: {
    flex: 1,
    color: "red",
    height: 50,
    borderWidth: 0,
    borderBottomWidth: 1
  }
});
```